# Getting excitement through people’s experience? A word to describe this situation!

Tags: word-request

I know there is a word that describes the situation when you get an excitement when, for instance, your friend tells you about their adventures.

I forgot the word.

Put differently, you get a sense of enthusiasm of other people’s experience as if you were involved!

Could you suggest a word to be the same or similar to the one I forgot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it isn't a single word that replaces *excitement through people's experiences*, I would use [**vicarious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vicarious):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : experienced or realized through imaginative or sympathetic participation in the experience of another
>   // a *vicarious* thrill

So:

> I felt *vicarious* excitement when hearing about her trip.
>   I was *vicariously* excited by his stories of adventure.

Comment: This is the word i was struggling to find!